# Returning structure from function gives me segmentation fault

Tags: c, data-structures, bitmap

So I'm trying to read bitmap header (the 54 bytes) and save it into structure using a function. But when I try to print the results, it gives me segmentation fault.

## bmp.c

```
#include "bmp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* BMP_file){
    if(BMP_file == NULL){
      return 0;
    }

    struct bmp_header* Header;

    memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));
    fread(&(Header->type), 2, 1, BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->size),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->reserved1),2,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->reserved2),2,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->offset),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->dib_size),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->width),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->height),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->planes),2,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->bpp),2,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->compression),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->image_size),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->x_ppm),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->y_ppm),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->num_colors),4,1,BMP_file); 
    fread(&(Header->important_colors),4,1,BMP_file); 
    return Header;
}
```

## bmp.h

```
#ifndef _BMP_H
#define _BMP_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define PADDING_CHAR "\0"

/**
 * Structure contains information about the type, size, layout, dimensions
 * and color format of a BMP file. Size of structure is 54 bytes.
*/
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (1/4/8/24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));


/**
 * Reads BMP header from input stream
 *
 * Reads and returns BMP header from opened input stream. The header is located
 * at it's beginning. If the stream is not opened or it is corrupted, function
 * returns `NULL`.
 *
 * @param stream opened stream, where the image data are located
 * @return `bmp_header` structure or `NULL`, if stream is not open or broken
 */
struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* stream);


#endif
```

## main.c

```
#include "bmp.c"

int main(){
  FILE *BMP_file = fopen("./assets/lenna.bmp", "rb");

  struct bmp_header* Header;
  memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));
  Header = read_bmp_header(BMP_file);
  printf("%x\n", Header->type); 
  fclose(BMP_file);
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried doing it by adding the structure "bmp_header" into function as a parameter (so the function would be void. But the thing is - bmp.h shouldn't be touched.

Comment: Did you run your program in a debugger? If not.... you probably know the follow up question... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code:

```
memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));
```

This does not fill a `struct bmp_header` with 0 but the pointer variable `Header`. As this pointer is probably much smaller than the header struct, you also fill memory areas that you are not supposed to touch.

If you don't get the segmentation fault already during this out-of-bounds access, you will get it immediately afterwards when you access the freshly created `NULL` pointer:

```
fread(&(Header->type), 2, 1, BMP_file);
```

Instead of filling with 0 you must provide memory first in `read_bmp_header`.

In `main` you do the same illegal `memset` operation. You must remove that operation completely. You assign a new value afterwards anyway.

You can solve the problem in 2 ways without changing `bmp.h`:

**Variant 1:**

Dynamic memory allocation in `read_bmp_header` and freeing in `main`.

```
struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* BMP_file){
    if(BMP_file == NULL){
      return NULL;
    }

    struct bmp_header* Header = malloc(sizeof(*Header);
    if (Header == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memset(Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));
    fread(&(Header->type), 2, 1, BMP_file);
    // TODO check result of read
    ...
    return Header;
}

int main(void)
{
   FILE *BMP_file = fopen("./assets/lenna.bmp", "rb");
   struct bmp_header* Header = read_bmp_header(BMP_file);
   fclose(BMP_file);

   printf("%x\n", Header->type); 
   free(Header); // Main must free the struct.
   return 0;
}
```

**Variant 2:**

Static memory is used in `read_bmp_header`; no freeing is required.

```
struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* BMP_file){
    static struct bmp_header Header;

    if(BMP_file == NULL){
      return NULL;
    }

    memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));
    fread(&Header.type, 2, 1, BMP_file); 
    // TODO: check result of read
    ...
    return &Header;
}

int main(void)
{
   FILE *BMP_file = fopen("./assets/lenna.bmp", "rb");
   struct bmp_header* Header = read_bmp_header(BMP_file);
   fclose(BMP_file);

   printf("%x\n", Header->type); 
   return 0;
}
```

This variant avoids dynamic memory allocation but can only handle 1 struct at a time and is not thread safe.

Comment: in variant 2,  this statement: `memset(&Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));` is not correct.  The passed parameter `Header` is already a pointer, so the statement should be: `memset(Header, 0, sizeof(struct bmp_header));`  Notice no `&` before `Header`

Comment: in variant 2, this statement: `fread(&Header.type, 2, 1, BMP_file);`  is not correct.  The passed parameter `Header` is already a pointer, so the statement should be: `fread( &Header->type, 2, 1, BMP_file);`  Notice the replacement of `.` with `->` .  Also, should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Oops, my error.  I must have been sleep walking when  reviewed your question, last night

Answer (score 0):

You are instatiating a pointer to the header with the line.

```
struct bmp_header* Header;
```

But it looks to me that you want to instantiate the actual object so try removing the * in all places you refer to `struct bmp_header`.

The segmentation fault actually will be coming from running `memset()` on `Header` which is actually an unitialised pointer.

Comment: But read_bmp_header() function returns a pointer, so I cannot remove *, that would be incompatible return types error.

Comment: `memset` is not used on an uninitialized pointer but on the address of `Header` which in general is valid. But this is not what is intented. Also the length is larget than the pointer, filling whatever happens to be in memory next to `Header`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, by saying

```
 struct bmp_header* Header;
```

you have just allocated memory for the pointer variable itself, but the pointer does not point to any valid memory. You need to make the pointer point to a valid memory location before you can make use of that.

That said, by the usage, it looks you don't need a pointer at all. Just define a variable of the structure type, and use that. Using

```
struct bmp_header Header;
```

should do the job.

Comment: But in main or is it the bmp.c?